# Rest API in Postman Error Message

Tags: rest

Can anyone help me to understand about my Error message in postman?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this thread. I answered this question few days back.

[Cannot get apexrest api call to work - INVALID_SESSION_ID](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241019/cannot-get-apexrest-api-call-to-work-invalid-session-id/241024?noredirect=1#comment366820_241024)